# objective c how to execute for loop in background queue and update view on each cycle of execution of for loop?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios7

I am making a chat messenger . I am selecting multiple images from the photo gallery and then sending them in a chat . I have run a for loop where each image is picked and send . This is working fine but UI updates when loop completes execution.

My Code is-

```
for (UIImage *cImage in selectedImages) {        
    NSBubbleData *rBubble = [NSBubbleData dataWithImage:cImage date:createdAt     type:BubbleTypeMine load:@"upload" key:key chatType:[chatWithUser objectForKey:@"type"]    sender:@"you"];
    rBubble.avatar = myPic;
    [bubbleData addObject:rBubble];
    [bubbleTable reloadData];
    [bubbleTable scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0, bubbleTable.contentSize.height -    bubbleTable.bounds.size.height, bubbleTable.bounds.size.width, bubbleTable.bounds.size.height) animated:YES];
    [globalManager.imageLoadingStatus setValue:path forKey:key];
}
```

Comment: You need to do UI updates in the main thread and give the main run loop some time to process them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the code into a block sending it to a background thread. Then each UI update is wrapped into another block, this time executed on the main thred.

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
dispatch_async(queue, ^{

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // perform on main

    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

> **dispatch_get_global_queue** is one of the solution for your requirement. This below
>   link gives the whole detail that how to update the UIView using
>   GCD(Global Central Despatch)

[Using Grand Central Dispatch for Asynchronous Table View Cells](http://ios.biomsoft.com/2014/02/02/using-grand-central-dispatch-for-asynchronous-table-view-cells/)

This may not be the solution, but you have to use the concept like this for updating the view on each cycle.